# Проблемы с проверкой на формат изображения

Tags: php, fileupload

как правильно проверить на формат изображение? Постоянно пишет неверный формат :/

Вот , что наделал

```php
// edit image
$id_user = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
$uploaddir = '../img/profileimg/';
$fot = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
$photo_size = $_FILES['uploadfile']['size'];
$type_image = $_FILES['uploadfile']['type'];
$fot_dir = $uploaddir.$fot;
if ($type_image == "uploadfile/.jpeg" || $type_image == "uploadfile/.png") {
  if ($photo_size < 1000000) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $fot_dir)) {
      $res = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `multi_login` SET `image` = '$fot_dir' WHERE `id` = '$id_user'");
      if ($res) {
        echo "<script>location='user?id=".$id_user.
        "'</script>";
      } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Шлях не доданий в базу даних, але файл завантажений!');location='user?id=".$id_user.
        "'</script>";
      }
    }
  } else {
    echo "<script>alert('Файл дуже великий!');location='user?id=".$id_user.
    "'</script>";
  }
} else {
  echo "<script>alert('Файл іншого формату!');location='user?id=".$id_user.
  "'</script>";
}
```

Comment: `Постоянно пишет неверный формат` прямо так и пишет? В коде таких слов нет

Comment: Чему равно `$type_image`? Mime типов `uploadfile/.jpeg` и `uploadfile/.png` не существует

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$type_image == "image/jpeg" || $type_image == "image/png"
```

попробуйте так

Comment: @Xelinel32 вместо `uploadfile` вставьте `image`